# equinox + sample.http - issue with tomcat 7

Tags: osgi, tomcat7, equinox

I am importing sample.http from http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php into eclipse , using tomcat 7 as server (linux platform). 
It shows several problems such as :

```
BundleActivator cannot be resolved to a type
No available bundle exports package 'javax.servlet.http'
```

and several such errors due to plugin dependencies not being imported.
(If I try with tomcat 6,it works).
Can someone point out what changes I should make for making the dependencies compatible with tomcat 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge jar.
It exports Servlet javax.servlet 2.3 but for Tomcat 7 you need javax.servlet 3.0

*Maybe* you can open up the jar file and fix that, but I have wasted quite some time with this construction, and never got it right. It is 5 years old, and that means trouble.

For me Felix worked a lot better, there is a clearer and more consistent explanation.

Take a look here: [apache felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-http-service.html#ApacheFelixHTTPService-UsingtheServletBridge)

I *think* with this setup you could still use Equinox with the FrameworkLauncher, if that is necessary